# Unity Global Menu Integration missing for some programs

Tags: unity, menu, panel, appmenu, globalmenu

First of All I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I don't remember this problem has ever been produced by the previous releases.

Unity Global Menu Integration is missing not for all the applications but some of them. Here it is the programs that can't integrate with Unity Global Menu:

- Software Center
- Gedit
- Geany
- Terminal
- Archive Manager
- Brasero
- Adobe Reader
- Document Viewer
- Filezilla
- ...

Some programs can still integrate their menus with the global menu, such as Firefox and File Manager.

I want The Global Menu Integration back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gedit, Terminal, Document Viewer and other programs *must* integrate, whereas Synaptic doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered. My question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that some of the programs you mention must integrate with Unity global menu, I suggest to check that you have the required packages.

I. Open **synaptic**

II. Search «appmenu» in Quick filter. According to me, these are the packages you must have installed:

[image]

Comment: They are all installed already.

Comment: Then you can try to «reset» unity to default. One way is by means of «ALT+F2 unity». Another way is with the use of Unity Tweak Tools

Comment: I tried `ALT+F2 unity`, no change.

Comment: In order to see if it is your config, create another user, log in and check if it has the same problem.

Comment: I was going to right this on my question: Guest account has the same problem. By the way, I have just tried Gnome3 PPA.Archive Manager's integration is now fixed.

Comment: Did you notice *when* did it all begin? It looks like you upgraded from 12.10 and something got wrong.

Comment: This problem started when I first installed Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install ubuntu-restricted-package

Comment: I have just uninstalled&installed again. As I expected, now problem is fixed.
I think the problem was related to the fact that My old installation iso was corrupted(I'm not sure,will check it if possible). This is because, I'd installed twice before my last installation and the problem had been reproduced by both in the same way.