# evince menus missing/scattered

Tags: unity, 18.04, menu, evince

Recently, the evince menus in the unity global menu bar have mostly gone missing on both my desktop and my laptop. Currently, there is only one pretty useless menu, "Document Viewer", in that bar.

I found the "missing" menu items behind some of the symbols in the top left or top right of the evince windows (not within the unity global menu bar, but just below it when the evince window is maximised).

However, I would prefer to have all the menus in one place, in the menu bar, as text. Is it possible to restore this behaviour? If so, how?

I found this (old) related question describing a similar problem: [Unity Global Menu Integration missing for some programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325654/unity-global-menu-integration-missing-for-some-programs) but the packages mentioned in the answer seem to have been superseded by the `*unity-gtk*` packages, which are installed.

Comment: Is it only `evince` missing menu options in the global menu bar or is it other applications like Firefox, Nautilus, etc?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Firefox, atom, dia, gimp, thunderbird, and gnome-terminal are OK (for some of those, the menu is in the window instead of the top bar, which is OK). Nautilus has only a single "Files" menu, so it has the same problems as well (not as big an issue as I mostly use keyboard shortcuts with nautilus). I also noticed it in eog (single "Image Viewer" global menu, symbol menus in the top right).

Comment: What release of Ubuntu? If it's 18.04 & evince 3.28 then what you now see is what you get, nothing to be done (unless you revert to evince 3.24..

Comment: @doug It's indeed 18.04 and 3.28. Bummer.

Comment: you could use the evince packages from 17.10, keeping in mind that you'd also need libgnome-desktop-3-12 (which can co-exist with libgnome-desktop-3-17) I've a bionic build of libgnome-desktop-3-12 in a ppa but you could use the 17.10 version also... Typically one has 4 evince source packages installed that need to be same version, sometimes a couple more, you'd need to gather all that you have already installed in the older version & replace all at once with dpkg..

Comment: F10 might  be the answer, although I don't know how to navigate that menu once it is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for the developers of evince instead of make it here. Please note that they remove the menubar in consciously. The issue that cause the removed of the menubar for evince is here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/433

They finally remove it here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/commit/8bb5fce0754aa0d2dc795d2d21ec778888dc3714

As currently exist an issue for more less the same question, the place where you can ask for that feature is here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/511