# Document Viewer (Evince) displays pdf-title instead of pdf-name in title-bar (also in 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, pdf, evince, titlebar

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 Document Viewer displays pdf title instead of name in the title bar (actually it displays a smaller name string under title in semi-transparency). This is very annoying especially when trying to switch between different pdf files opened simultaneously, since you cannot recognize the correct file from the title. I know that this used to be an old problem of Evince but I wonder why it appeared again, and if there is a way to change this behaviour.

**update**
After brand new installation of 20.04, Evince version 3.36.7 still has the same behavior: displays pdf-title instead of pdf-name in title-bar. I think it is a big flaw in Document Viewer, for the reason explained above (99% of times the pdf-title is meaningless).

Comment: Likely another flaw in the evince version used in 18.04 & newer. Just like this other flaw you can put up with or use the previous version of evince. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061953/evince-menus-missing-scattered#comment1746033_1061953

Comment: For now I used this old workaround: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1829931 . It still works. It would be nice if they implemented an option to select if displaying title or name of pdf's, like for instance in other readers (like Okular...)

Comment: Actually it seems to be the rebirth of an old bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/78584 https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=386292

Comment: Thank you @doug but I was not able to re-install an older version of Evince following your indications

Comment: should work fine if you aquired the 4 17.10 & older libgnome-desktop-3-12 packages needed. More of a forum question as how to exactly do that..

Comment: The only solution that I've found is to compile a new customized version of Evince where I switched the role of Window title and subtitle. I hope that this behavior will be fixed in next versions.

Comment: Is this maybe related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1923459  If so, it would be fixed in 21.10.